# Meteor: Custom sign up process using Autoform

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I've been trying (and ~succeeding) to use Autoform to create a custom registration process for my users.

I am using Collection2 along with it and have created a `RegistrationSchema` for my Autoform fields and handle validation.

The process is as follow : 
- Use autoform with a meteor method and the custom schema
- In the meteor method use `Account.createUser`

The issue here is that when using `Account.createUser` server side (because we are in a meteor method) it does not log the user in. 
What I did there is to pass to user email and password to the meteor method's callback, running on the client side (see the files `server - methods.js` and `client - sign-up.js` in the gist) and then perform the login.

https://gist.github.com/gabriel-dehan/3f78d94f6a035c89595d

It works fine but seems really really not secure, passing the user credentials around like this.

Is this problematic ? If so, how could I fix that ? I see two options :
- Do a server side login but I have no clue how to.
- Transfer the `Account.createUser` logic onto the client, but as autoform calls the server side Meteor.method I don't know how to tell him to call a client method.

Any takes on this issue ? It would be great !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe server side login is possible, unless there was a way to hand back the login token through the meteor method and then call login in the callback.

If your using simpleschema just for the validation aspect, I would use a client side validator such as mesosphere https://atmospherejs.com/copleykj/mesosphere  and throw out autoform for the login, since you only need three inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, if I don't find any other way I'll do this, but having 2 validations packages seems a bit too much !

Answer (score 0):

Found this...

It might help you with what you are working on.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/200